# MediaPlayer playing STREAM_NOTIFICATION interrupted music playback

Tags: android

In my app, I use the following code to play a short notification sound using MediaPlayer with STREAM_NOTIFICATION. The issue is that, when the app plays the notification sound and at the same time music is played at background by music player app, the notification sound will interrupt (pause) the music playing. How can I make my app's notification sound to be played simultaneously with the background music playback? Thanks.

```
  AssetFileDescriptor afd =
      mResources.openRawResourceFd(resId);
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
  afd.close();
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
      }
    });
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
  mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Take a look at the "Request the Audio Focus" and the "Duck!" section of the official Android Dev doc: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour described in the question seems to be specific for Android 5.x and below. For Android 6.x and above AudioManager behavior has changed and AudioSystem.STREAM_NOTIFICATION flag doesn't interrupt music playback anymore.

As workaround I would recommend to replace

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

by

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

P.S. Not sure what exactly changed in Android platform but according to
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r37/media/java/android/media/AudioAttributes.java and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.0_r26/media/java/android/media/AudioAttributes.java they treat AudioSystem.STREAM_NOTIFICATION as AudioSystem.STREAM_SYSTEM for both Android 5.x & 6.x:

```
public Builder setInternalLegacyStreamType(int streamType) {
        switch(streamType) {
            /*...*/
            case AudioSystem.STREAM_SYSTEM:
                mContentType = CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION;
                break;
            /*...*/
            case AudioSystem.STREAM_NOTIFICATION:
                mContentType = CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION;
                break;
            /*...*/
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid stream type " + streamType + " for AudioAttributes");
        }
        mUsage = usageForLegacyStreamType(streamType);
        return this;
    }
```